# Los QLineEdit no aceptan Ñ ni acentos

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

Los `QLineEdit` no me aceptan "ñ" ni acentos.

Todo va bien en el programa hasta que escribo "ñ", este problema se soluciona en los `QLabel` colocando una "u" antes de la cadena de texto pero en el `QLineEdit` no se como resolverlo.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class ejemplo(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ejemplo,self).__init__()
        self.ventana()

    def ventana(self):   
        self.Salida = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.Salida.setGeometry(120, 10, 200, 25)

        self.Entrada = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.Entrada.setGeometry(10, 10, 100, 25)
        self.Entrada.textChanged.connect(self.F)

        self.setWindowTitle("Ventana")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 300)
        self.show()

    def F(self):
        self.Salida.setText(str(self.Entrada.text()))


def main():        
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Ej  = ejemplo()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QLineEdit` si que acepta caracteres Unicode sin problemas. El error es que estás intentando pasar un objeto [`PyQt4.QtCore.QString`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstring.html#details) (que es lo que retorna `self.Entrada.text` y que usa Unicode), a `str` en Python  2 (equivalente a `bytes` en Python 3).

Cuando haces:

```
 self.Salida.setText(str(self.Entrada.text()))
```

Lo que estas intentando es forzar la conversión de un string Unicode a ASCII, por lo que si ingresas un carácter no ASCII, como la "ñ", obtienes un error de encode:

> Excepción "unhandled UnicodeEncodeError"
>   'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Para pesarle el texto a otros Widgets no necesitas hacer nada, basta con:

```
self.Salida.setText(self.Entrada.text())
```

Si necesitas trabajar con el string en Python (por ejemplo imprimirlo, parsearlo, etc) puedes pasarlo a un tipo unicode de Python con:

```
unicode_string = unicode(self.Entrada.text())
```

O usar los métodos propios de [`QString`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstring.html#details) para obtener un `QByteArray` con la cadena codificada correctamente para un determinado formato de codificación (UTF-8, Latin-1, etc) siempre que ese carácter exista en el:

```
unicode_string = unicode(self.Entrada.text().toUtf8(),  encoding = "utf-8")
```

---

```
unicode_string = unicode(self.Entrada.text().toLatin1(),  encoding = "latin-1")
```